# Trouble with understanding proof for cardioid as an envelope of a pencil of lines

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, vectors, polar-coordinates

[image]
I would like to make sense of this proof for a cardioid as an envelope of a pencil of lines in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid) article, but I don't recognise most of the notation and equations used in it. So far, I only know:

1. The dot syntax refers to a derivative
2. The T symbol stands for transpose and means that the normal vector should be treated as a column vector.

However, I am still very confused about:

- How they got the equation of the tangent
- How they got the normal vector form the parametric equations

[image]

- Where the two points in the "secant line passing the two points" are

[image]

and so on, which I have not been able to find anything about. Could someone please tell me what I would have to learn to fully understand this proof?

Comment: Related: ["Why intersection of chords form a cardioid?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4278244/409) ... Not a duplicate, because this question is about understanding a particular proof. Nevertheless, OP and others may be interested in seeing other proofs.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting!

Comment: Have a look at the first part of this previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774670/305862) of mine.